# How do Material Icons set the icon based on the content of the element?

Tags: html, css, fonts, material-design, google-material-icons

How do the icons with the following structure work?

```html
<span class="material-icons">
   accessibility_new
</span>
```

I have been poking around the [Material Icons repo](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) trying to understand how the icon is determined by the content of the HTML but cannot for the life of me figure it out.

I suspect it has something to do with the [actual font files](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/font), but when I try to open them in Font Forge nothing loads.

**EDIT:** I understand how to use Material Icons themselves, but I am trying to understand how to recreate this functionality with my own icon font.

Answer (score -2):

Generally with this, you would have run:

```
npm i material-icons
```

so they would live in your project (look at your package.json file!). So, when you specify a certain icon like accessibility_new, then you are simply referencing the library that lives in your project folder. Does this answer your question?